# PHP - Script fails to find class after including another file

Tags: php, include

Sorry, tough to explain in the title.

This is taken from the Amazon MWS API

```
include_once ('feed/src/Service/Samples/.config.inc.php');
include_once ('products/src/ServiceProducts/Samples/GetMatchingProductForIdSample.php');
```

Script which includes a Class from these files works just fine.

However, if I add:

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

The same script fails because

`Class 'MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client' not found`

I checked the directories and after every point the directory is the same. Why can it not find this class simply after including PHPMailer?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding use `\products\src\ServiceProducts\Samples\GetMatchingProductForIdSample` to the top of the script.

Comment: Sorry, 'use' ? I'm not familiar with that syntax

Comment: It looks like your script is having a namespace conflict between the second and third file you've added. The use keyword tells the script which file to use for which class: [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: I see. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Try using just the PHPMailer class instead of using the autoloader to install the PHPMailer class.  That might give you a clue.

Comment: How would I do that? Seems the autoload.php is required to invoke the classes.

Comment: Reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241899/php-mailer-error-autoload-file , suggests phpmailer doesn't come with an autoloader anymore.  It would be nice to have a version number (please) here so we can glance the autoload code.  Sounds like a bug.  What if you use composer to install Phpmailer and use composer's autoloader?  Can you also add your Php version please.